# 2006 f150 severe hesitation weird question

Tags: ford, f-150, maf, throttle-position-sensor

- low rpm hesitation, very severe until (usually) waiting for higher geare
- clean mafs, clean throttle body
- no sounds from vac lines, no visible tears
- while cleaning throttle body I noticed the plate was not 100% closed; not sure if this is normal for drive by wire since I only worked on older

The following is from a short turn on, wait for idle, accelerate gradually in park to 3k then turn off.
Thank you

[image]

Comment: Around 12s I start to see WOT for the TPS